# Magento 2 TransportBuilder Uncaught Error: Call to a member function createAttachment() on null

Tags: magento2, email-templates, attachment, email-attachment

Magento 2.4.2 I am trying to send an attachment in the mail but getting  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function createAttachment() on null in /Vendor/Module/Model/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php:10

di.xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
 
    <preference for="\Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder" />
</config>


$this->_transportBuilder
            ->setTemplateIdentifier('monthly_invoice')
            ->setTemplateOptions(
                [
                    'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                    'store' => $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId(),
                ]
            )
            ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
            ->setFrom($senderInfo)
            ->addTo($emails)
            ->addAttachment(file_get_contents($attachment)); //Attachment goes here
```

transportbuilderfile attachment

```
        <?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Mail\Template;
use Zend_Mime;

class TransportBuilder extends \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
{
    public function addAttachment($body) {
//        $this->message->createAttachment((string)$body, 'application/pdf', \Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
//           \Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64, 'attachment.pdf');
         $this->message->createAttachment(
            $body,
            'application/pdf',
            \Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
            \Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
            'attatched.pdf'
        );
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Fallowed below links
https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/email-attachment-from-observer/td-p/77122

https://www.magemonkeys.com/magento-2-add-file-attachment-in-email-using-custom-module/

can any one tell me solution how to send pdf attachment

Comment: Because your not passing argument values and calling on null;

Comment: @ZahidH can you check my update answer. which argument can you please tell me

Comment: It looks ok but try it if produce any error or exception paste here.

Comment: @ZahidH  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function createAttachment() on null in /var/www/html/app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php:10

Comment: Make sure have you override correctly? did you added core class or dependency injection of *Magento\Framework\Mail\Template* in di.xml? also compile code correctly, also check error log

Comment: @ZahidH can you please elaborate your solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134525/discussion-between-pawankumar-and-zahid-h).

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is just that you forgot to call the constructor class that's why you  don't have the message variable initialized.

Constructor coming from

`Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder`

```
public function __construct(FactoryInterface $templateFactory, MessageInterface $message, SenderResolverInterface $senderResolver, ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager, TransportInterfaceFactory $mailTransportFactory, MessageInterfaceFactory $messageFactory = null, EmailMessageInterfaceFactory $emailMessageInterfaceFactory = null, MimeMessageInterfaceFactory $mimeMessageInterfaceFactory = null, MimePartInterfaceFactory $mimePartInterfaceFactory = null, AddressConverter $addressConverter = null)
{
    parent::__construct($templateFactory, $message, $senderResolver, $objectManager, $mailTransportFactory, $messageFactory, $emailMessageInterfaceFactory, $mimeMessageInterfaceFactory, $mimePartInterfaceFactory, $addressConverter);
}
```

Comment: I added but no use same error